# Output formatting within \message

Tags: compiling, terminal-output

Is there a list or overview of character codes that can be used within `\message` or `\typeout` to format the printed string in pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-… (TeX Live 2017)?

I know of `^^J` which does a line break. Are there more?

```
\documentclass{minimal}\makeatletter
\message{^^J==> Hello^^JWorld! <==^^J}
\typeout{^^J==> Hello^^JWorld! <==^^J}
\@@end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\message` does full expansion on its argument. Unexpandable tokens will be represented as themselves; control sequences will be preceded by the `\escapechar` (if nonnegative) and followed by a space if they are control words. If `\newlinechar` is nonnegative, the corresponding character will produce a line break.

The following plain TeX file `lupino.tex` shows the features.

```
\def\Now#1{Now#1}

\message{^^J\Now\space you can^^J\relax^^J}

\newlinechar=`^^J

\message{^^J\Now\space you can^^J\relax^^J}

\escapechar=-1

\message{^^J\Now\space you can^^J\relax^^J}

\end
```

The console output will be

```
This is TeX, Version 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2018) (preloaded format=tex)
(./lupino.tex ^^JNow you can^^J\relax ^^J 
Now you can
\relax 

Now you can
relax 
 )
No pages of output.
Transcript written on lupino.log.
```

There's no difference if you run `pdftex` instead of `tex`.

Plain TeX doesn't set `\newlinechar`, LaTeX sets it to 10 with

```
\newlinechar=`^^J
```

Answer (score 3):

essentially `\message` has no other formatting, `^^J` is not built in, any character with code the value of `\newlinechar` is not printed but instead forces a newline. The latex sources have:

```
\newlinechar`\^^J
```

Comment: Say, i wanted `^^T` to do a line break and four spaces (tab). Would it be possible to "teach" this to `\message`? I know that I could define a macro that does that. And i noted by experimenting that  `^^k` for unstance produces a + while other letters produce different symbols, others (like `^^T`) throw errors. Is there something i can read to understand whats happening with `^^-char`?

Comment: you could make it active but why not just use a local definition of say `\def\\\{^^J\space\space\space\space}` and use `\\ ` ?

Comment: This question was less about "how do i use X to achieve Y" but rather "i want to understand what X is and how X works; Y is an example."